# 415 Unsupported Media Type - Does not work for GET

Tags: java, rest

I have a rest Call which returns the name of the session user

```
@GET
    @Produces(" text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8")
    @Path(value = "getSessionUserName")
    public Response getSessionUserName() {

        try {

            Session session = SessionManager.getCurrentSession();
            String details = session.getUserDisplayName().toString();
            return Response.ok(details).build();
        } 
        catch(Exception e) {
            return handleExceptions(e);
        }
```

Every time I try to access this, I am getting a 415 Unsupported Media type exception.
I have other calls which are almost identical and are working fine. I cannot figure out the problem with this one.

Answer (score 0):

`@Produces` allow either a single String media type (not a single string with multiple comma separated media types), or a comma separated list of single string media types

```
@Produces("application/xml")

-or-

@Produces({"text/html","application/xhtml+xml","application/xml;q=0.9", "*/*;q=0.8"})
```

Another thing, you might want to go through the Wikipedia article on [Content Negotiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_negotiation). I think you may not fully understand how it works. What you have in your produces is what the browser would send. It is saying that it *wants* the data back in HTML, XHTML, or if those aren't available, then XML, and if that isn't available, then give me anything.

But on the server side, you need to decide what types are are actually able to produce. Can you actually produce HTML, can you actually produce XHTML, can you actually produce XML? The `@Produces` annotation works with content negotiation. There are "advertising" what media types are you are able to produce. The client should send an `Accept` header with the media types it is able to handle. That's where the negotiation happens. If the client wants a type, the server can't produce, it will get a 406 Not Acceptable error. That's how ConNeg works.